# Slow HTTP Load with the Assets Folder of the Project - Ruby on Rails, Webrick, Localhost, Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webrick, firefox4

## The HTTP Protocol:

***Notice:** The cache has been cleared before recording the HTTP protocol.*

This is a ***HTTP protocol*** of the ***HTTP Watch*** Addon for ***Firefox***: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?wccimru3qdu19s2#

The ***HTTP load*** is around `5 seconds`.

The ***status code*** is `200 OK`.

## The Problem:

To load the `assets` folder into the `cache` Firefox does not do the `GET` request just on the ***first time*** of rendering the web application - it also does it repeatedly on every page load, so that ***every page rendering*** becomes too slow.

## The Questions:

1. Is there something specific in ***Webrick, Ruby, or Rails***, which may cause
   Firefox to do the repeated `GET` request?
2. The ***HTTP load*** takes around `5 seconds` on the ***first time***
   rendering of the web application, so the `assets` folder can be
   loaded in the `cache` of ***Firefox*** - are there procedures to increase
   the load speed?

## The Addendum:

Installing the `rails-dev-tweaks` has increased the speed time from around `5 seconds` to around `2.5 seconds`. Where, by now, the repeated `GET` request is still a persisting problem, which means that around `2.5 seconds` for ***each page load*** is still too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
rails-dev-tweaks
```

https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks

to your Gemfile for 'development' environment...

Currently the issue should only be in dev env., in production it should be working fine already

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - yet I am getting an error, when trying to install the package: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command rails-dev-tweaks`

Comment: have you added it to your gemfile ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it has worked out. Nevertheless, installing it has increased the speed time from around `5 seconds` to around `2.5 seconds`. Where, by now, the repeated `GET` request is still a persisting problem, which means that around `2.5 seconds` for ***each page load*** is still too slow.

Comment: by looking to webrick logs on your console..can you identify which part is actually taking time. Is it actually the GET rquest to your action, or the later ones i.e. loading of js/assets..

Comment: Also can you run your app once with `-e production` and notice if any considerable issue in that environment..?

Comment: To answer your second comment, when starting it with `-e production` I am getting the error message `ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):`. I can also provide the processing protocol, if there is interest for that.

Comment: You would have to do `config.assets.compile = true` in your production.rb environment file   OR you can keep it false and run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` once before rails s in prodution mode

Comment: To answer your other question. It are specific `JavaScript (.js)` `file types` at `15 ms`, and at the end it is the `application.js` at `218 ms`.